# Size of a byte array golang

Tags: go, arrays, sizeof

I have a []byte object and I want to get the size of it in bytes. Is there an equivalent to C's sizeof() in golang? If not, Can you suggest other ways to get the same?

Comment: Do you want the length, the capacity, or the size in memory? They may all be different.

Comment: No, len gives you the number of objects in an array not the size in terms of bytes of the whole array. I guess  @evanmcdonnal got it right..

Comment: @sr_149: you don't get the size of the array with `binary.Size`, you get the `length * data_type_size`. This may be what you want, but remember the size of the array (capacity) is often different.

Comment: @JimB that's false. You're conflating slice and array, there is no capacity with array and if you were to do a black box comparison of that against the same in C with `sizeof` it would return to the `length * data_type_size`. Meaning they are functionally equivalent. see; https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/6 - slice is the next slide.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal: no I'm not. I chose my words carefully, and the question was about a *slice* (`[]byte`), where the capacity is the size of the underlying *array*; __the *array* pointed to by the field `array` in the slice struct__. The closest equivalent of C's `sizeof` would return the entire array's allocated size, not the portion you were using.

Comment: @JimB I didn't read the question as specifying between the two however I guess the syntax used is technically a slice. In most case capacity is probably not the desired value though. If you do want that you should just make your own method that does `cap(bytes) * unsafe.Sizeof(bytes[0])`

Comment: JimB and @evanmcdonnal Thank you for the clarification, although the question reads "size of byte array", the array is the return result of io.ReadFile() api. And I ended up using the binary.Size() api to get the number of bytes read. Would this give me the right values?

Comment: @sr_149: there's no reason to do that. Just use `len` on the returned slice from `ioutil.ReadFile`, or the `n` value of `io.ReadFull` (not sure which you meant, since there is no `io.ReadFile`)

Answer (score 34):

To return the number of bytes in a byte slice use the `len` function:

```
bs := make([]byte, 1000)
sz := len(bs)
// sz == 1000
```

If you mean the number of bytes in the underlying array use `cap` instead:

```
bs := make([]byte, 1000, 2000)
sz := cap(bs)
// sz == 2000
```

A byte is guaranteed to be one byte: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Size_and_alignment_guarantees.

Comment: Thanks @Caleb, the godoc definitely helped clear things up further!

Answer (score 11):

I think your best bet would be;

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "encoding/binary"

func main() {
    thousandBytes := make([]byte, 1000)
    tenBytes := make([]byte, 10)
    fmt.Println(binary.Size(tenBytes))
    fmt.Println(binary.Size(thousandBytes))
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/HhJif66VwY

Though there are many options, like just importing unsafe and using sizeof;

```
import unsafe "unsafe"

size := unsafe.Sizeof(bytes)
```

Note that for some types, like slices, `Sizeof` is going to give you the size of the slice descriptor which is likely not what you want. Also, bear in mind the length and capacity of the slice are different and the value returned by binary.Size reflects the length.

Comment: It's not just easy to get the size of the slice descriptor with Sizeof,  you *only* get the size of the descriptor which is always 3 words.

Comment: Thank you! :D shall use the encoding/binary pkg

Comment: @JimB yes but the OP might be dealing with a byte array in which case it works; https://play.golang.org/p/UQUcQYC9F3 personally I think the binary package works better because it won't give you the slice descriptors size but the OP did as for the equivalent of sizeof which is unsafe.Sizeof.